# Symfony2 ORM schema update with 2 FK

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

hi i'm trying to link a class test with 2 entities, the Administrator that post the test and the competence (subject of the test ), but whatever i do i only get 1 index FK on my database after schema update

```
namespace Admin\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjetCompetenceListe")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_competence", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idCompetence;

    /**
     * @var \Administrateur
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Administrateur")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_administrateur", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idAdministrateur;
```

please can any one tell me why ?

Comment: You mean schema update doesnt add the relation between your tables Administrateur and test? you may need to clear doctrine meta data, php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating indexes with @index annotation, maybe you should give it a try. [Ref](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index)

add index with @index annotation and then run schema update command

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clear doctrine meta data :

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Otherwise do a :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

to check if the relations are correct.